# What is fast to execute and low on CPU - Reading Denormalized data from db (stored as binary) in table or Reading the same from binary file?

Tags: database, performance, serialization, io, cpu-usage

When it comes to performance for e-commerce site, what do you suggest from following two options:

1. Reading Serialized De-normalized data stored in separate table in db as binary? 
   OR
2. Reading Serialized De-normalized data stored in file as binary?

With at least three tables / binary file to be read for each page request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. because to store it in a file you must first write it out of your db?

Comment: And what is fast as far as reading is concerned - db or file?

Comment: Pure reading could be faster on the DB if you have some kind of particularly fast data-link (thats how the cool kids do it). For most configuration, local disk access will be faster then network communication. BUT in your scenario you are still reading the DB to write the file? Additionally, writing to the file is particularly challenging bottleneck. In most cases its best to request the file from the DB.